# Apache name-based virtual hosts configured, but both hostnames direct to the same site

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, apache-virtualhost

I have an apache2 webserver running perfectly on my Raspberry Pi (raspbian) and I recently wanted to make another site. To do this, I am trying to make use of name based virtual hosts. I've obtained another dynamic dns host name from https://my.noip.com/#!/dynamic-dns. I believe I have configured my 2 site conf files correctly and the hosts file.

My two websites are called ashwingupta.ddns.net and javacloudcompile.ddns.net (which is the one I had previously). However, if I connect to either one, I now get the site for ashwingupta.ddns.net. The following are the config files:

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   raspberrypi
127.0.1.1       javacloudcompile.ddns.net
127.0.0.1       ashwingupta.ddns.net
```

**javacloudcompile.ddns.net.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName javacloudcompile.ddns.net
    ServerAdmin ashiwingupta@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts/javacloudcompile.ddns.net/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**ashwingupta.ddns.net.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName ashwingupta.ddns.net
    ServerAdmin ashiwingupta@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts/ashwingupta.ddns.net/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I've enabled both sites w/ `a2ensite` and both claim to have been enabaled correctly. I then refreshed apache w/ `service apache2 restart`.

(Note, everything is intentionally on 8080, my ISP blocks inbound on 80)

edit: Forgot to mention, I do have `Listen 8080` in my ports.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that the NOIP service is calling your server via a frame, and the frame source is your server's IP address, rather than a domain name:

```
<frame src="http://68.101.98.197:8080" name="redir_frame" frameborder=0>
```

Your Apache server isn't receiving the server name with the request. Since the conf files are loaded in alphabetical order, ashwingupta.ddns.net.conf has the highest priority and is seen as the primary or default server (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

One way around this would be to use a different port for ashwingupta.ddns.net, e.g. port 8081, assuming you can specify that port number in the NOIP configuration.

Comment: ah thanks, I'll try this when I get a chance and let you know!

Comment: is there any other free domain service I might be able to use that you know of?